# AngularJS HammerJS IOS Refreshes Web Site

Tags: iphone, ios, angularjs, angularjs-directive, hammer.js

i have a problem with angularjs + hammerjs. After some time of tapping, reload of a web site happens, its random and I don't know why. I read somewhere, that hm-tap has a problem with 400ms waiting for next tap.

I'm using angularjs 1.1.5 and hammerjs 1.0.5.

Did anyone experience the same problem.

I isolated the problem. When normal fast tap is used it works ok, but when i hold+tap, then web site reloads.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add ng-href attribute.

```
<a ng-href="homepage link" hm-tap="function()">Link</a>
```